# How to generate SQL query with automatically joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose I have SQL (MySQL) database, which schema defines some relationships like foreign and primary key. If I build a query with such tables, I would most often join these tables exactly as it defined in schema.

Is there any tool to generate such queries? May be tool can accept column names and output a join clause?

Comment: Can you provide some example output? At the moment it's sounding like you just need to define a `view`

Comment: Okay, may be you are just right...